# Pushing ViewController from side menu not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, menu, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm coding a side menu like the one with the contacts in Facebook app. I want that when the user selects one contact, the menu closes and the TopViewController pushes the chat. The problem is that using the following code, it only closes the menu.

```
 "Menu.m"

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chat"];
    [self.slidingViewController.topViewController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
}
```

Comment: You should log some of your entities (self.slidingViewController, self.slidingViewController.topViewController, and self.slidingViewController.topViewController.navigationController) to see if any are nil.

Comment: I'll do it and I tell you something.

Comment: I get that: Self.slidingViewController.topviewcontroller.navigationcontroller: (null). But I don't understand why because if I call this method in the TopViewController it works.

Comment: Do you know why it is null? @rdelmar

Comment: No, not without seeing the structure of your app.

Answer (score -1):

these are the good tutorials for what you want to archive [side menu](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) and [facebook style slide menu](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path)

Comment: That isn't what I asked for. I want to push a viewcontroller in the navigation controller. Both are just pushing a viewcontroller.